# Spring Data- JPA multiple nested Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a class structure something like below:

```
public class X {

@Id
private Long id;

//One to one mapping
private Y y;

....Some more attibutes

}

public class Y {

@Id
private Long id;

//ManyToOne mapping
private Z z;

....Some more attibutes

}

public class Z {

@Id
private Long id;

....Some more attibutes

}
```

Now I have a Respository interface like below

```
public interface XRepository extends JPARepository<X, Long> {
    // This is not working,    
    public X findByIdAndYIdAndZId(Long xId, Long yId, Long zId);
    
    //This also doesn't work obviously for same reason as above one
    public X findYIdAndZId(Long yId, Long zId);

}
```

I am getting this exception

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property zId found for type X!
```

Please help me on how to construct the method for such scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field `Z` does not exist in `X`, it is in `Y` class. So, you should use the full path of the object for `Z`'s `id`.

```
public X findByIdAndYIdAndYZId(Long xId, Long yId, Long zId);
```

*Note:* Please consider to use the understandable name for the class. I guess they are for example only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;`**  annotation.

```
 @Query("{$and : [{'y.id': ?0}, {'y.z.id': ?1 }]}")
 public X findByIdAndYIdAndZId(Long yId, Long zId);
```

You will get more idea about [**`Query`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Query.html)

Comment: I know I could do it using Query but I wanted to use method.